# How do i display 2 interfaces on the same app based on different credentials?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I am making an app in Android Studio which will be used by teachers and students in a university.

How do I make it so that teachers and students get different interfaces based on their credentials?

I haven't tried anything yet but the idea I had was that it'll read the username first and then redirect users to their respective screens since the credentials are different.

Comment: Use an if statement based on some attribute and launch the relevant interface.

Comment: @RyanM an if statement for the username? if it reads and validates a teacher's username, it'll take them to their screen and the same thing for students?

Comment: Alex Mamo's answer describes basically what I was saying, but in much more detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The idea I had was that it'll read the username first and then redirect users to their respective screens since the credentials are different.

If you want to read the username and then compare the credentials, it means that you have to store the credentials in the database, which is not really a good idea. It's very important **not** to store sensitive data like passwords in plain text in the database. Malicious users might take advantage of that. I recommend you use [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth) and right after that secure the database using [Firestore Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started).

So it's not about their credentials as much as it is about the type of user. So I'll recommend you use a Firestore database with a schema that looks like this:

```
db
|
--- users (collection)
     |
     --- $uid (document)
     |     |
     |     --- name: "Saurabh Pathak"
     |     |
     |     --- type: "teacher"
     |
     --- $uid (document)
           |
           --- name: "Alex Mamo"
           |
           --- type: "student"
```

Now, assuming that you have already created two activities for each type of user, `TeacherActivity` and `StudentActivity`, to redirect each user to their corresponding activities, then please use the following lines of code written in Java:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference usersRef = db.child("users");
DatabaseReference uidRef = db.child(uid);
uidRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            DataSnapshot sanpshot = task.getResult();
            if(sanpshot.exists()) {
                String type = sanpshot.child("type").getValue(Long.class);
                if(type.equals("teacher")) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TeacherActivity.class));
                } else {
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), StudentActivity.class));
                }
            }
        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", task.getException().getMessage()); //Never ignore potential errors!
        }
    }
});
```