# How to make admin and user login using Firebase Realtime database

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

The expertFragment() which shows lists of all users (except the current user). What I want is to divide users in two types- 1. Expert 2. normal Users.
And to show experts to users and users to expert.

Expert should logIn and through their assigned id & password while the user can sign in and log in.
Experts account should be created mannuly in Firebase Realtime Database with the key in the user 'isExpert'.

What I tried-

```
   class ExpertFragment : Fragment(), iExpertAdapter {

private var _binding: FragmentExpertBinding? = null
private val binding get() = _binding!!

private lateinit var adapter: ExpertAdapter
private lateinit var expertList: ArrayList<User>

private lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth
private lateinit var dbRef: DatabaseReference


override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {

    _binding = FragmentExpertBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    val root: View = binding.root

    auth = Firebase.auth
    dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference

    expertList = ArrayList()
    adapter = ExpertAdapter(this.requireContext(),expertList,this)

    binding.expertRecylerView.adapter = adapter

    dbRef.child("user").addValueEventListener(object: ValueEventListener{
        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {

            expertList.clear()
            for(postSnapshot in snapshot.children){

                val currentUser = postSnapshot.getValue(User::class.java)

                if(auth.currentUser?.uid != currentUser?.uid && currentUser!!.isExpert){
                    expertList.add(currentUser!!)
                }
            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

        }

        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {

        }

    })

        return root
}

override fun onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView()
    _binding = null
}

override fun onConsultBtnClicked(v:View, name: String?, uid: String) {
    val bundle = bundleOf("name" to name,"uid" to uid)
    v.findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_navigation_expert_to_chatFragment,bundle)


}
```

}

```
  data class User(
val uid: String = "",
val name: String? = "",
val mail: String? = null,
val phoneNo: String? = null,
val address: String? = null,

val vehicleModleNo: String? = null,
val vehicleRegYear: String? = null,
val vehicleName: String? = null,
val rtoNo: String? = null,
val distanceTraveled: String? = null,

val isExpert: Boolean = false
```

)

But writing this **&& currentUser!!.isExpert** in the if block hides all the users from the fragment.

```
  if(auth.currentUser?.uid != currentUser?.uid && currentUser!!.isExpert){
                    expertList.add(currentUser!!)
                }
```

Comment: The `!!` will always return null. How can null "empty" be an expert when no value is assigned. What your doing is throwing a Null Pointer Exception. So from what I see you are replacing null (empty) with null (empty) so your result is null (empty).. that's what I am seeing

Comment: if I remove this !!, it shows error. Also, if I removes '&& currentUser!!.isExpert' from the if statement the program runs fine and shows all the users.

Comment: Have you solved the issue? I recently answered a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76169767/how-do-i-display-2-interfaces-on-the-same-app-based-on-different-credentials/76169963#76169963), maybe it will help.

Comment: Thanks @Alex it helped me. I made  a new variable of 'isExpert' to get current user type and then used if-else conditions. I have added my answer code below, though I doubt if I could make it more clean.

Answer (score 1):

1. Double bang is used for definite value when you want to compare the value you can use nullable as well

   **instead of** currentUser!!.isExpert

   **use** currentUser?.isExpert == true

this will check whether the current user is nullable or not. after this expert will be checked with true value.

2. Boolean value is not read directly in the data model when mapped from firestore and realtime database. User JVMField annotation to read it

**@field:JvmField**

val isExpert: Boolean = false

Comment: Thanks Amanpreet! it worked. Now, the only experts are showing to the users. But when I log in as an Expert, it shows other experts instead of users.

Comment: You would have do the same thing as the answer in reverse. If you don't want expert to see expert but only users then if expert is logged in then the expert list will be hidden and only show users. This would be the "else" portion of the if statement.

Comment: @CampNerd I tried using `else` and copying that same in it, but it didn't worked, don't know why. But what worked for me is - getting current user `isExpert` status then doing the above thing in `if-else`. I posted my answer you can check and it would be great if you can suggest any other approaches.

Answer (score 0):

```
    dbRef.child("user").addValueEventListener(object: ValueEventListener{
        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {

            expertList.clear()

            // getting current user isExpert status.
            val isExpert = snapshot.child(auth.currentUser!!.uid).child("isExpert").value
            Log.e("isExpert",isExpert.toString())

            for(postSnapshot in snapshot.children){

                val currentUser = postSnapshot.getValue(User::class.java)

                // if currentUser is an Expert then only users will be visible
                if(isExpert == true) {
                    if (auth.currentUser?.uid != currentUser?.uid && currentUser?.isExpert == false) {
                        expertList.add(currentUser!!)
                    }
                }
                // if currentUser is a user then only experts will be visible
                else{
                    if (auth.currentUser?.uid != currentUser?.uid && currentUser?.isExpert == true) {
                        expertList.add(currentUser!!)
                    }
                }

            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

        }

        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {

        }

    })
```

Reference- [How do i display 2 interfaces on the same app based on different credentials?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76169767/how-do-i-display-2-interfaces-on-the-same-app-based-on-different-credentials/76169963#76169963)

Comment: Look at this way.. isExpert == true ... Vs... isExpert == false... The false will show only the current user list.. so look at your code and think how you would position the code to only show those lists to the appropriate user. Then you can follow up with the else portion of the statement

Comment: if(isExpert == true) {
                    if (auth.currentUser?.uid != currentUser?.uid && currentUser?.isExpert == false) {
                        expertList.add(currentUser!!)
                    }
                }.  Now do the opposite

Comment: I am showing you how to do it so you can learn. If it gets to the point to where you still don't understand I will post the answer. But look closely at the code. Example ... If (isExpert == true){ do something} ... If (isExpert != true) { do something) ... Else { do something}

Comment: Hey @CampNerd I think I did the same in the above answer which I added but still if I am not getting what you wanna explain then you can write your answer.